# PowerShell [uri] Types Accelerator produces different AbsoluteUri

Tags: powershell, uri, powershell-5.1

I have a local file ($URLsFile), which contains a list of URLs:

```
http://WIND451325/Dev/Application.aspx__%__dev.com
http://WIND451326/Dev/Application.aspx__%__dev.com
```

When using the [uri] Types Accelerator with the Get-Content command:

```
[uri[]]$ArrayURLs = Get-Content -Path $URLsFile
```

I've noticed some changes in the value of the **AbsoluteUri** property, as `__%__` changed to `__%25__` :

```
foreach ($item in $ArrayURLs)
{
    $item.AbsoluteUri
}

http://WIND451325/Dev/Application.aspx__%25__dev.com
http://WIND451326/Dev/Application.aspx__%25__dev.com
```

After going through the official documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_accelerators?view=powershell-5.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=net-7.0

I could not find any reference to the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [overload with `dontEscape`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-uri-ctor(system-string-system-boolean)) set to `$true`.

```bash
$ArrayURLs = Get-Content -Path $URLsFile |
    ForEach-Object { [uri]::new($_, $true) }
```

This ctor is obsolete, in newer versions of **PowerShell 7+**, you should use the [`UriCreationOptions` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-uri-ctor(system-string-system-uricreationoptions@)) instead.

```bash
$options = [System.UriCreationOptions]@{
    DangerousDisablePathAndQueryCanonicalization = $true
}

$ArrayURLs = Get-Content -Path $URLsFile |
    ForEach-Object { [uri]::new($_, [ref] $options) }
```

Comment: thanks. So If I understand correctly, when the URLs in my local file, are being converted to a URI object in the level of PowerShell, there is also a manner of URLs escape characters that need to be addressed?

Comment: @edwio it doesnt necessarily have to be an URL in your local file. The `%` is escaped in this case because it is a special character in URIs, `[uri]::EscapeUriString('%')` outputs `%25` which is why you see it in your `AbsoluteUri` property.